# Factory Pattern for Role Based security

Tags: c#, factory-pattern, facet, role-base-authorization

I am asked to implement Role-Based Security to production code(actually to a particular method) with no change to concrete class. The hint was given using Factory Class. I have no clues. Any help?

Comment: -1: No concrete question/effort to solve. Side note: modifying production code based on "hint" is probably not the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what is factory pattern is ? If you understand what is factory pattern then you will get some idea how to implement.

In Simple words **Factory Pattern** is

> Provide an interface for creating families of related or dependent
>   objects without specifying their concrete classes.

[Read here](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAbstract.aspx#_self1) for more infomoration.